# greatest-n-per-group with condition and joining to large table (or query for getting amount in national currency when holes in currency rates table)

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I read most relevant Q/A on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group tag but doesn't found solution for my task as details differ.

I have a table with *amount*/*currency*/*date* and have a task to convert *amount* to *amount in national equivalent* on that *date*.

One problem that currency exchange rate table have holes so direct joint on *amount*/*currency*/*date* give **null**. As rule of thumb - in such case business rules dictate that you can get last available rate for given *amount*/*currency*.

My dumb solution:

```
select p.AMOUNT * cr.RATE from PAYMENT p
  join CURRENCY_RATE cr on cr.CURRENCY = p.CURRENCY
    and cr.DATE = (select max(subcr.DATE) from CURRENCY_RATE subcr
                     where subcr.CURRENCY = cr.CURRENCY and subcr.DATE <= p.DATE)
```

give very bad execution plan (this is simplified query, original have a lot of **full table scans**, **hash joins** due to additional business logic).

Query work on large set of `PAYMENT`, table accessed by **full scan**.

Many `CURRENCY`/`DATE` pairs was queried from `CURRENCY_RATE`. I don't really sure that using index on pair as **first in index range scan** will be good strategy to retrieve pairs...

I use Oracle and don't understand if windowed function applicable in that situation when `max(...) over (partition by ...)` also must have additional condition...

**UPDATE** I plan to use query for data migration and importing tasks, so really have no filter on `PAYMENT`. I start thinking that I can import with `p.AMOUNT * cr.RATE` ever if it **null** and then update incomplete records with above query. This look promising as holes very rare occur in `CURRENCY_RATE`.

Another solution that I see - to use materialized view or another table which have no holes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

latest currencies by "max" with  "group py":

```
select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from CURRENCY_RATE cr
  where cr.dt = (select max(subcr.DT) from CURRENCY_RATE subcr where subcr.COUNTRY = cr.COUNTRY and subcr.CURRENCY = cr.CURRENCY group by subcr.CURRENCY, subcr.COUNTRY);

-- too long
select count (*) from (
  select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from CURRENCY_RATE cr
    where cr.dt = (select max(subcr.DT) from CURRENCY_RATE subcr where subcr.COUNTRY = cr.COUNTRY and subcr.CURRENCY = cr.CURRENCY group by subcr.CURRENCY, subcr.COUNTRY));
```

latest currencies by "not exist":

```
select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from CURRENCY_RATE cr
  where not exists (select 1 from CURRENCY_RATE subcr where subcr.COUNTRY = cr.COUNTRY and subcr.CURRENCY = cr.CURRENCY and subcr.dt > cr.dt);

-- tooo long....
select count (*) from (
  select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from CURRENCY_RATE cr
    where not exists (select 1 from CURRENCY_RATE subcr where subcr.COUNTRY = cr.COUNTRY and cr.CURRENCY = subcr.CURRENCY and subcr.dt > cr.dt));
```

latest currencies by "join" and "is null":

```
-- Too long...
select cr1.* from CURRENCY_RATE cr1
  left join CURRENCY_RATE cr2
    on (cr1.COUNTRY = cr2.COUNTRY and cr1.CURRENCY = cr2.CURRENCY and cr2.DT > cr1.DT)
  where cr2.DT is null;
```

latest currencies by "row_number() over (partition by ... order by ...)":

```
with maxcr as (
  select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE, row_number() over (partition by cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY order by cr.DT desc) as rown
    from CURRENCY_RATE cr
) select * from  maxcr
  where maxcr.rown = 1;

select maxcr.COUNTRY, maxcr.CURRENCY, maxcr.RATE from (
  select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE, row_number() over (partition by cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY order by cr.DT desc) as rown
    from CURRENCY_RATE cr) maxcr
  where maxcr.rown = 1;

-- 2.5 sec
select count(*) from (
  select maxcr.COUNTRY, maxcr.CURRENCY, maxcr.RATE from (
    select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE, row_number() over (partition by cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY order by cr.DT desc) as rown
      from CURRENCY_RATE cr) maxcr
    where maxcr.rown = 1);
```

latest currencies by "max" and "in":

```
select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from CURRENCY_RATE cr
  where (cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.dt) in (select subcr.COUNTRY, subcr.CURRENCY, max(subcr.DT) from CURRENCY_RATE subcr group by subcr.COUNTRY, subcr.CURRENCY);

-- .250 sec
select count(*) from (
  select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from CURRENCY_RATE cr
    where (cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.dt) in (select subcr.COUNTRY, subcr.CURRENCY, max(subcr.DT) from CURRENCY_RATE subcr group by subcr.COUNTRY, subcr.CURRENCY));

-- 2.3 sec
update DATA_2 inc
  set inc.MONEY_CNV = inc.MONEY_V * (
    select cr1.RATE from (
        select comp.COMPANY COMPANY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from COMPANY comp
          join CURRENCY_RATE cr on (cr.COUNTRY = comp.COUNTRY)
          where (cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.dt) in (select subcr.COUNTRY, subcr.CURRENCY, max(subcr.DT) from CURRENCY_RATE subcr group by subcr.COUNTRY, subcr.CURRENCY)) cr1
      where cr1.COMPANY = inc.COMPANY and cr1.CURRENCY = inc.CODE_V)
  where inc.INC_DATE > DATE '2014-01-01';
```

latest currencies by "max" and "=":

```
select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from CURRENCY_RATE cr
  where cr.dt = (select max(subcr.DT) from CURRENCY_RATE subcr where subcr.COUNTRY = cr.COUNTRY and subcr.CURRENCY = cr.CURRENCY);

-- .250 sec
select count (*) from (
  select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from CURRENCY_RATE cr
    where cr.dt = (select max(subcr.DT) from CURRENCY_RATE subcr where subcr.COUNTRY = cr.COUNTRY and subcr.CURRENCY = cr.CURRENCY));

with cr1 as (select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from CURRENCY_RATE cr
  where cr.dt = (select max(subcr.DT) from CURRENCY_RATE subcr where subcr.COUNTRY = cr.COUNTRY and cr.CURRENCY = subcr.CURRENCY)
) select comp.COMPANY, cr1.CURRENCY, cr1.RATE from cr1
  join COMPANY comp on cr1.COUNTRY = comp.COUNTRY;

-- .250 sec
with cr1 as (select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from CURRENCY_RATE cr
  where cr.dt = (select max(subcr.DT) from CURRENCY_RATE subcr where subcr.COUNTRY = cr.COUNTRY and cr.CURRENCY = subcr.CURRENCY)
) select count(*) from cr1
  join COMPANY comp on cr1.COUNTRY = comp.COUNTRY;

with cr1 as (
  select comp.COMPANY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from COMPANY comp
    join CURRENCY_RATE cr on cr.COUNTRY = comp.COUNTRY
    where cr.dt = (select max(subcr.DT) from CURRENCY_RATE subcr where subcr.COUNTRY = comp.COUNTRY and cr.CURRENCY = subcr.CURRENCY)
) select count(*) from cr1;

-- 3 sec
update DATA_2 inc
  set inc.MONEY_CNV = inc.MONEY_V * (
    select cr1.RATE from (
        select comp.COMPANY COMPANY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from COMPANY comp
          join CURRENCY_RATE cr on (cr.COUNTRY = comp.COUNTRY)
          where cr.dt = (select max(subcr.DT) from CURRENCY_RATE subcr
                           where subcr.COUNTRY = comp.COUNTRY and cr.CURRENCY = subcr.CURRENCY)) cr1
      where cr1.COMPANY = inc.COMPANY and cr1.CURRENCY = inc.CODE_V)
  where inc.INC_DATE > DATE '2014-01-01';
```

latest currencies by "max" with  "group py" and "join":

```
select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from CURRENCY_RATE cr
  join (select subcr.CURRENCY, subcr.COUNTRY, max(subcr.DT) dt from CURRENCY_RATE subcr group by subcr.CURRENCY, subcr.COUNTRY) maxcr
    on maxcr.COUNTRY = cr.COUNTRY and maxcr.CURRENCY = cr.CURRENCY and maxcr.dt = cr.DT;

-- .250 sec
select count (*) from (
  select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from CURRENCY_RATE cr
    join (select subcr.CURRENCY, subcr.COUNTRY, max(subcr.DT) dt from CURRENCY_RATE subcr group by subcr.CURRENCY, subcr.COUNTRY) maxcr
      on maxcr.COUNTRY = cr.COUNTRY and maxcr.CURRENCY = cr.CURRENCY and maxcr.dt = cr.DT);

with cr1 as (
  select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from CURRENCY_RATE cr
    join (select subcr.CURRENCY, subcr.COUNTRY, max(subcr.DT) dt from CURRENCY_RATE subcr group by subcr.CURRENCY, subcr.COUNTRY) maxcr
      on maxcr.COUNTRY = cr.COUNTRY and maxcr.CURRENCY = cr.CURRENCY and maxcr.dt = cr.DT
) select comp.COMPANY, cr1.CURRENCY, cr1.RATE from cr1
  join COMPANY comp on cr1.COUNTRY = comp.COUNTRY;

-- .300 sec
with cr1 as (
  select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from CURRENCY_RATE cr
    join (select subcr.CURRENCY, subcr.COUNTRY, max(subcr.DT) dt from CURRENCY_RATE subcr group by subcr.CURRENCY, subcr.COUNTRY) maxcr
      on maxcr.COUNTRY = cr.COUNTRY and maxcr.CURRENCY = cr.CURRENCY and maxcr.dt = cr.DT
) select count(*) from cr1
  join COMPANY comp on cr1.COUNTRY = comp.COUNTRY;
```

latest N currencies:

```
-- Vendor independent by tooo slow...
select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE from CURRENCY_RATE cr
  left outer join CURRENCY_RATE cr2
    on (cr2.COUNTRY = cr.COUNTRY and cr2.CURRENCY = cr.CURRENCY and cr2.DT >= cr.DT)
  group by cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE
  having count(*) <= 3
  order by cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE;

-- Very fast (full table scan).
select cr.COUNTRY, cr.CURRENCY, cr.RATE, cr.DT from (
    select subcr.*, row_number() over (partition by subcr.COUNTRY, subcr.CURRENCY order by subcr.DT) rown from CURRENCY_RATE subcr) cr
  where cr.rown <= 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try a query like this:

```
SELECT
    A.AMOUNT * A.RATE
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            P.AMOUNT,
            CR.RATE,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.ROWID ORDER BY CR.DATE DESC) AS RN
        FROM
            PAYMENT P
        INNER JOIN CURRENCY_RATE CR
        ON
            P.CURRENCY = CR.CURRENCY
            AND
            P.DATE >= CR.DATE
    ) A
WHERE
    A.RN = 1
```

Here are some things to watch out for:

1. Using reserved words like `DATE` and `CURRENCY` can cause conflicts in name resolution.
2. The query will exclude rows from `PAYMENT` that have no matching rows in `CURRENCY_RATE`.  If you want to include such rows, use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.
3. If the combination of `CURRENCY` and `DATE` in `CURRENCY RATE` is not unique, the query will arbitrarily select one of the rows.  If you want to select a specific row in this case, add expressions as necessary to the `ORDER BY` clause so that the row you want will come first.
4. If `PAYMENT` has a unique, non-null key, you can use this in place of `P.ROWID` in the `PARTITION BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

From your SQL, I understand that you are trying to display all the records from PAYMENT table, as it does not have any filters. Try to use currency as filter. 
If you really need all records to be displayed without filters, then you have to update the rate.payment column if NULL at the time of INSERT itself. 
Then for displaying you can just use `"Select p.AMOUNT * cr.RATE from PAYMENT p"`     alone.